# How to select which iOS device receives push notifications (for Facebook)

Tags: ios, notifications, facebook, apns

I've got an iPad 2 and an iPhone 3GS, both of which have the official Facebook app. Since I set up Facebook on my iPad, only my iPad has been receiving notifications from Facebook. (I think this might also be the case with other apps.)

Ideally I'd like to receive notifications on both devices. Is this possible?

If not, how do I select which device receives notifications? Is it a simple matter of turning off notifications for a given app on one device, and leaving them on for the other?

Comment: As the Push Notification service sends notifications to every registered device for a certain event, you should get notifications on every device you turned this feature on. Which in return means that you are right when you say that turning off the notifications on one device will let you choose that only the other device gets them.

Comment: I have them switched on on both devices, both within the Facebook app, and in the Notification settings. Somehow, since asking my question, I have managed to switch which device is receiving the notifications. But I still haven't been able to receive notifications on both devices at once yet.

Answer (score 4):

Just of note that Facebook is notorious for being extremely flakey when delivering notifications of any kind (whether they be system wide through the home screen icon, or even in-app). If you have Push enabled on both devices, the problems could lie within Facebook.

Also note that it may (read: should) be the case that when you check your account on one device, the notifications should disappear on the other, as they will be marked as read.

Additionally, it could be that Facebook's servers deliver a notification only once to any waiting device capable of handling them (remember they have millions of users to contend with). You'll have to contact Facebook to make certain of this however.

You can use mail to test it. If you send yourself an email, do you receive notifications on both devices? If you read the mail, do they disappear (get marked as read) on both devices?

Comment: Facebook's notification system is massively flakey, I imagine it's sending it, classing one device as having 'read' it and then stopping at that stage.

Answer (score 2):

Push notifications are device specific. Check your settings, and ensure both devices have them on.